# Provision Ubuntu Server bootable USB stick with wifi credentials and enable ssh server

Tags: ubuntu, setup, ubuntu-22.04

I have a bootable USB stick with Ubuntu Server 22.04 LTS. The stick looks like this:

```
dr-xr-xr-x  1 sebastian sebastian 2,0K Apr 21 08:14 ./
drwxr-x---+ 3 root      root      4,0K Aug  9 15:07 ../
dr-xr-xr-x  1 sebastian sebastian 2,0K Apr 16 00:08 boot/
-r--r--r--  1 sebastian sebastian 2,0K Apr 21 08:14 boot.catalog
dr-xr-xr-x  1 sebastian sebastian 4,0K Apr 21 08:14 casper/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 sebastian sebastian 2,0K Apr 21 08:14 .disk/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 sebastian sebastian 2,0K Apr 21 08:14 dists/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 sebastian sebastian 2,0K Apr 16 00:08 EFI/
dr-xr-xr-x  1 sebastian sebastian 2,0K Apr 21 08:14 install/
-r--r--r--  1 sebastian sebastian  12K Apr 21 08:14 md5sum.txt
dr-xr-xr-x  1 sebastian sebastian 2,0K Apr 21 08:14 pool/
lr-xr-xr-x  1 sebastian sebastian    1 Apr 21 08:14 ubuntu -> ./
```

But now (before I install the machine) I want to configure some stuff in advance. I want to ...

1. ... set the hostname
2. ... have the machine connect to my wifi right away (so I want to put my wifi connection information onto the stick)
3. ... enable SSH so I can connect from another machine

Anyone got a idea how I can do that? Thanks guys and best regards.

Comment: The solution is in your directory listing: `casper` can do this for you.

Comment: And how can I add the information there?

Comment: Just to make it clear: I want to install a machine with wifi and ssh on. I do not want to use the stick as a Live system running on the usb stick.